# Обратиться к методу через string

Tags: c#, файлы

Делаю что-то типа игры на формах, и в ней есть система чата, которая берёт все диалоги, варианты ответов и всё остальное из отдельного файла (в виде string).

Мне нужно, чтобы варианты ответа как-то влияли на итог диалога, поэтому задумался о  том, чтобы в тот самый файл записать методы, которые будут исполняться в случае выбора определённых ответов.

Возможно ли каким-то образом имея строку (string) обратиться к методу, название которого указано в ней? А если нет, то есть ли какие-то другие варианты для решения данного вопроса.

Comment: Можно, вам необходимо изучить такой инструмент, как [рефлексия](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/14.1.php), очень мощный механизм. В принципе, если начать с базовых вещей (у методов не будет параметров) особо и несложно. Вот допустим простой пример на en so: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6469027/5752652

Comment: @A K спасибо, сейчас взгляну 

Comment: Или проще: составить `Dictionary<string, Action>`, т. к. имя процедуры для скрипта не обязано совпадать с именем в коде.

Comment: Без конкретного кода, который не работает, не получиться дать конкретный ответ. Мне кажется, здесь можно обойтись без рефлексии. А когда можно без нее обойтись, то нужно без нее обойтись.